# What do you call a pair of words with opposite meanings that differ only by a prefix?

Tags: terminology, antonyms, negative-prefixes

In general, words with opposite meanings are called antonyms.  Is there a word that describes the subset of antonyms that are different only by a prefix where the prefix negates the meaning of the root word?

For instance, `hot` and `cold` are antonyms, but don't share a root and would not be described by the term I am looking for.

`Paired` and `unpaired` are antonyms and share the same root `paired`.  These words would be described by the term I am looking for.

Other examples:

- `Typical` - `Atypical`
- `Intended` - `Unintended`
- `Enfranchised` - `Disenfranchised`

Lost positives would be a special case of this type of word where only the negated sense of the word is in use, e.g. `disgruntled` is a commonly used word, but `gruntled` is not.

A bonus answer would point to a list of such negating prefixes.

Comment: I've only heard them called Antonyms, which isn't specific enough to this situation.

Comment: Congress - Progress

Comment: Is it quite as simple as that? I know of words which have more than one "paired negative" - e.g. *interested* gives rise to both *uninterested* and *disinterested*, which have entirely different meanings.

Comment: I don't think having more than one paired negative changes the question in any way I can see.  The examples only had one paired negative, but multiple mappings seem acceptable, such as uninterested->interested and disinterested->interested as suggested.

Comment: Affixed antonyms? But I totally made that up on the spot. It seems to me that these are more just words with affixes that only become opposites because you paired them. Also, are these two lists what you had been looking for? [List 1](https://thirumalganesh.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/english-antonyms-list-using-dis-il-im-in-ir-and-un-prefix/), [list 2](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/negatives.shtml).

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang, List 1 would be perfect if it were all-inclusive and I could use it as a lookup table.  I might try to create the complete list from a combination and code and manual review.  I am starting to think that there is no word and we should start one.  Affixed Antonyms is a good candidate.

Comment: Do not know if there is an answer to this, but maybe cognate antonyms would work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a book that might interest you about antonyms in English.

***[Antonyms in English: Construals, Constructions and Canonicity](http://www.worldcat.org/title/antonyms-in-english-construals-constructions-and-canonicity/oclc/756578637)***
by  Steven Jones

There's a whole chapter on the difference between "canonical antonym pairs" (such as good/bad) and what the author call "negated antonymous" words (such as good/not good) and if they're an affixal or non affixal negation (such as not happy vs unhappy) . On page 151 the author call these pairs of words that differ only by their affix...

> **affixal antonyms**

as opposed to "lexical antonyms"
note that by using the plural of *antonym* it implies automatically the pair of words with opposite meaning, there's no need to add "pair". 
[image]