# Is there a word that describes repeating the same word but changing the prefix?

Tags: single-word-requests

To begin with, thank you for your help. I am looking for a word that describes repetition of word with a change of its prefix. My only thought is "the repetition of affixed antonyms." This is derived from a question I found on this site, ["What do you call a pair of words with opposite meanings that differ only by a prefix?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366122/what-do-you-call-a-pair-of-words-with-opposite-meanings-that-differ-only-by-a-pr). Any type of word would work. The following is an excerpt from my literary essay. For context, this would refer to the use of fortune and misfortune:

> The narrator comments, “those who had no share in the good fortunes of the mighty / Often have a share in their misfortunes” (20). The author uses *blank* to juxtapose...

Thank you!

Comment: Antonyms based on the same word?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.literarydevices.com/polyptoton/

**Polyptoton** is a device in which there is a repetition of words with the same root for rhetorical effect.

> This short excerpt from Polonius in William Shakespeare’s Hamlet
> carries many examples both of simple repetition and of polyptoton. The
> repetitions of “tis true,” “tis pity,” and “mad” are just
> that—repetitions. Then we see Polonius’s verbal prowess continue with
> the polyptoton examples of “defect” and “defective” as well as
> “remains” and “remainder.” Indeed, “effect” and “defect” are also
> polyptoton examples because they share the same etymological origin of
> the Latin suffix “-fect,” which means “to do.” **The words are opposite,
> yet share a common root.**